# Static initializer where the property name is the same as an object name

Tags: c#, .net, initialization

I have an API returning some object, call it `ObjectA`. In reality this is never returned on it's own, the responses which carry this data are of one of the following forms;

```
{
   "Status":"Success",
   "ObjectA": {
          "Prop1":"Value",
          "Prop2":"Value"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "Status":"Success",
    "ObjectAs": [
        {
           // instances of ObjectA
        } 
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update this object. It's done by supplying the properties you'd like to update as the body of a PUT. At first I thought the object would be the entire body, after talking to the API team I learned that it actually should be of the form;

```
{
    "ObjectA": {
        "PropToUpdate":"NewValue"
    }
}
```

The issue here is that I was using;

```
  string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { PropToUpdate = "SomeValue" });
```

However, this now needs to be something like the following which won't compile;

```
  string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ObjectA = new { PropToUpdate = "SomeValue" }});
```

Is there any work around for this situation? I think the reasons for that not compiling are fairly obvious and  I know of a couple of works arounds (don't use static initilization or change the class name in the client), is there any way achieve the desired result without using either of the work arounds I mentioned? Is there possibly a precompiler direction like `@` for string literals that will allow me to use static initilization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ObjectA = new { PropToUpdate = "SomeValue" } })
// indented, that's

{
  "ObjectA": {
    "PropToUpdate": "SomeValue"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a bad habit of posting questions that have obvious answers due to me overlooking syntax errors.